# A condition for a function to be of separated variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $u(x,y)$ be a $C^2$ function. If $u$ satisfies $u u_{xy}=u_xu_y$, then how can I prove that $u$ is of the form $u(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$? Here the subscript means the partial derivative.

Comment: Is $u\cdot u_{xy}$ or $u_{xy}$? I'm asking if there is a typo.

Comment: Look at $w=\ln|u|$, perhaps?

Comment: @manooosh it is the former.

Comment: @HansLundmark Could you give me more hints?

Comment: Well, it was just a though, and I haven't tried it, but if $u$ is multiplicatively separated, then $w$ is additively separated, and what would $w_{xy}$ be in that case...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=e^v$. We have

$$uu_{xy}=u_xu_y\iff e^v(v_{xy}+v_xv_y)e^v=v_xe^vv_ye^v$$ and $v_{xy}=0$. Hence

$$v=f(x)+g(y)$$ and $$u=e^{f(x)}e^{g(y)}.$$